# How to make a text button which speeds up text animation

Tags: python, tkinter

So basically, I have text which is typed out character by character. with the code:

```
text = "test"

delta = 40
delay = 0
for i in range(len(text) + 1):
    s = test_string[:i]
    update_text = lambda s=s: canvas.itemconfigure(variable, text=s)
    canvas.after(delay, update_text)
    delay += delta
```

This is all inside of a function, lets call: def NewEvent(). What I want to do is create a text button with the text "Skip" which changes delta to a lower number, thus speeding up the animation upon click. I cant seem to figure it out, normally when you make text clickable, it has something along the lines of:

```
skipbutton = canvas.create_text((400,100), activefill="Medium Turquoise", text="Skip", fill="White", font=('Arial', 30), tags="skip")
canvas.tag_bind('skip', '<ButtonPress-1>', function)
```

The problem is, it needs to stay within the same function. So I thought of creating an if statement similar like this:

```
if delta is 40 and skip is ____:
    delta = 10
```

However, I dont know what would come after- (skip is) for it to work, or even if this would work at all... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should probably move to an OO setup and then you can just save things as instance variables.

Comment: if you need text button then maybe use `Button( ..., command=function)`

Comment: if you want to change speed during animation then you can't do it in easy way because you use `after` to create at once all update_text callbacks. You will have to use `after_cancel` to delete all callbacks and use `after` again to create new callbacks with new `delta`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing animation in a way that makes your problem very difficult to solve. The problem is that you are scheduling all of the frames of animation before you display the first frame. In order to change the speed you would have to cancel all of the pending jobs and recreate new jobs. This is not the proper way to do animation in Tkinter.

A better solution is to only have a single job active at one time. You do this by having a function that displays one frame of animation and then schedules itself to run again in the future.

The general structure looks like this:

```
def animate():
    <draw one frame of animation>
    if <there are more frames>:
        root.after(delay, animate)
```

In your case, each "frame" is simply adding one character to a character string, and your condition at the end is to simply check to see if there are more characters.

A simple implementation is to pass a string into the `animate` function, have it pull the first character off of the string and append it to the display.

For example:

```
def update_text(text):
    char = text[0]
    remainder = text[1:]
    current_string = canvas.itemcget(variable, "text")
    new_string = current_string + char
    canvas.itemconfigure(variable, text=new_string)
    if len(remainder) > 0:
        canvas.after(delay, update_text, remainder)
```

To start the animation, give it the string you want to display:

```
update_text("Hello, world")
```

This this function depends on a global variable for the delay, writing a function to speed the animation up or slow it down only requires that you modify this delay:

```
def speedup():
    global delay
    delay = int(delay/2)
```

You can call it from a button quite easily:

```
tk.Button(root, text="Speed up!", command=speedup)
```

Comment: How would you implement this into code you already have, ive been trying to figure it out. Ive replaced the variable with the variable that the canvas text is set to. I took a screenshot of the code I have for the function im in, http://prntscr.com/9upxf5